# Same Text format inExcel

Tags: excel

I have one excel Workbook name as "Description". In that sheet have one column like below.

```
1.Adjust Fuel Injector
2.Adjust break elevator
```

now i want to change the second row as like first row.(i.e) I want to change the All the first letter should be capital letters.Example:Adjust Break Elevator.

Comment: user2902589, consider about [accepting answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). It's the way of saying "Thank you very much" in SO.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a worksheet function:

```
 =PROPER()
```

PROPER can also be used in VBA (as `Application.Proper`)

In VBA you can also use

```
cell.Value = StrConv(cell.Value, vbProperCase)
```